# Trim leading and trailing spaces from each request parameters in Struts1.1

Tags: java, servlets, struts-1

I am using Struts1.1 in a web application. My requirement is to trim leading and trailing spaces from the request parameters of each request.
We are fetching request parameters through Struts form instead of fetching it through request.

Trimming spaces from each request parameter at the time of fetching it is not at all good approach. Since filter is not used in my application, I am thinking of any other option to do this?

What approach can I follow to do this?

Comment: If you want to have this done "automatically", why not using a filter?

Comment: `String` has `.trim()`, you know

Comment: use `String` class's `trim()` in setter methods for parameters.

Comment: Using trim in setters across an entire application is a waste of time when better options exist. The only time that might be a reasonable solution is if you need trim control at a very granular level.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a filter.
2. Implement a custom request processor.

Which approach depends on what else is already in the project; if you already have a custom request processor I'd probably do it there instead of introducing a new filter. If you don't, a filter is drop-dead easy and could be used when you upgrade your ancient version of Struts.